# React Native: Failed to launch emulator - "The emulator quit before it finished opening"

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I'm encountering an issue while trying to run my React Native project on Android using npx react-native run-android. The error message I'm receiving is:

> Failed to launch emulator. Reason: The emulator quit before it
> finished opening. You can try starting the emulator manually from the
> terminal with: emulator @INFO | Storing crashdata in:
> /tmp/android-mypc/emu-crash-34.1.18.db, detection is enabled for
> process: 21525.

I've tried running the emulator manually as suggested, but I'm still facing the same problem. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

I'm using a macOS system.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue that appears to be related to the Android emulator v34.x.x. Specifically, the `emulator -list-avds` command seems to have a problem when running React Native (I was using v34.2.19). To resolve this, you only need to follow the steps provided in the following link, in order, to install the previous stable emulator manually. This should solve the problem:

https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me.

Follow these steps and you will fix it.

https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1801#issuecomment-1980580355

Answer (score 0):

The Same issue happened to me.

This bug came from the command line `emulator -list-avds`.

My Solution:

For time being I go to Android Studio and run emulator firstly when it starts. Then I start metro and emulator command to develop...